# Class manager - memory pool?

Tags: c++, memory-management

So right now I have something like this (oversimplified):

```
class Person
{
    unsigned int ID:
    ........
};

class ClassManager
{
    std::vector<Person*> _Persons;

    Person* create()
    {
        Person* person = new Person();
        unsigned int id = _Persons.size();
        person->ID = id;
        _Persons.push_back(person);

    }
    Person* get(unsigned int ID)
    {
        return _Persions[ID];
    }
};
```

I was wondering if something like this would be more efficient:

```
class ClassManager
{
    static const unsigned int DEFAULT_COUNT = 4
    Person* memoryPool;
    unsigned int count;
    unsigned int index;

    void init()
    {
        memoryPool = new            Person[DEFAULT_COUNT];
        count = DEFAULT_COUNT;
        index = 0;

    }

    Person* create()
    {
         Person* person = &memoryPool[index];
         person->ID = index;
         index += 1;
         return person;
    }
    Person* get(unsigned int ID)
    {
        return &memoryPool(ID);
    }
};
```

....and then I'd just resize memoryPool if I need more Persons. Again, just a very simplified version of what i plan to make it. I just have a bunch of these objects and an object manager for each object, and it's probably more efficient to have a memory pool for each object manager, rather than dynamically creating each individual object (there could be hundreds).

Would this be a better approach? Thanks.

Comment: Could you just use an std::vector<Person>? I believe the vector class already has a good internal memory allocation algorithm.

Comment: There is different behavior of two examples. In second `DEFAULT_COUNT` constructors of `Person` class will be called in `init`. But in first only one constructor will be called in `create` function.

Comment: You left out the required code that reallocates the array.  In itself a very good reason to not do this.  It is pretty unlikely you'll see the difference, heap implementations these days are already very good and don't skimp on the important stuff, like ensuring that allocating from multiple threads doesn't cause trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is certainly more efficient. Allocation of each single object is costly compared to allocation of bulks of objects.

What is missing from your code sample is handling of the exhaustion of the pool in the manager's create function (perhaps due to oversimplification of the code sample).

Additionally you might want to consider reuse of allocated objects, i.e. reuse of Person instances once they are no longer needed. This will spare you the need to allocate more objects.

Consider using a template class for a memory pool of an abstract object and embedding such a pool class in each object manager – instanced for the object type of that manager. Once an object is no longer needed it should be returned to the manager and into the pool for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Is there merit to the approach generally speaking? Perhaps. Before you rush in to implement, ask yourself why would you want to do this? Has performance analysis indicated a hot-spot you are trying to eliminate? Are you trying to move memory allocations out of a critical section?

Remember that there's a cost associated with this - and not just in runtime performance that you can quantify. There's the cost in lines of code that must be written, debugged and maintained.